# Generating html from php file but leave out the form on the page?

Tags: php, html

I am using file_put_contents, ob_get_contents to generate a static html page from the entire php page. there is a HTML form on the PHP page which will be generated in the html as well.

the form has an ID of myForm.

what i need to do is to generate the HTML as it is but leave out the "myForm". basically I don't want the form in the newly created HTML page.

Here is what i use to generate the html page from my PHP page:

```
<?php 
if ((isset($_POST["music1"])) && (isset($_POST["music2"])))  
{ 

file_put_contents($options[$_POST['music1']].'+'.'and'.'+'.$options[$_POST['music2']].'.html', ob_get_contents());


}
// end buffering and displaying page
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

is there anyway to target the "myForm" ID while the html page is being created and opt it out?

**EDIT:** this question is not duplicated as far as i can see. I am not asking "how to use simple html dom parser"! that's why i specifically provided the code that I am using which is ob_get_clean. I am not sure if i am missing something?

EDIT:

This is what I have now and it doesn't work:

```
    <?php 
    if ((isset($_POST["music1"])) && (isset($_POST["music2"])))  
    { 

    $foo = '
    <style>
        #myForm {
          display: none;
        }
    </style>
</header>';
$finalHTML = str_replace('</header>', $foo, $currentHTML);file_put_contents($options[$_POST['music1']].'+'.'and'.'+'.$options[$_POST['music2']].'.html', ob_get_contents());


    }
    // end buffering and displaying page
    ob_end_flush();

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove entire `<form id="myForm>...</form>` tag or only `id="myForm"` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php

Comment: I think you are looking at ob_start and ob_get_clean filter out the form, probably using DomDocument.

Comment: @VahidHallaji, i need to remove the entire <form id="myForm>...</form> .

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, i have already seen that. Thanks. but none of the answers on that question was related to mine. apart from the second answer which was "Try Simple HTML Dom Parser" but I am not using HTML Dom parser. I am using file_put_contents. am i missing something?

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx: DOM parsers are used on an HTML string.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, any chance you could explain further please?

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx: Please do read the manual entry on the PHP DOM extension. It's filled with examples and helpful advice. Basically, you give it an HTML string, and then you can manipulate it in the same way you can in JavaScript (not jQuery)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha why duplicate? this question doesn't need extensive DOM parsing, I explained a quick hack in my answer.

Comment: Because your answer is just that. A hack, and not the proper way. It's enough that your html is one character out of what you expect it to, and your script breaks without a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add a CSS?

```
<style>
    #myform {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Edit:
How about trying this hack:

```
$foo = '
    <style>
        #myForm {
          display: none;
        }
    </style>
</header>';
$finalHTML = str_replace('</header>', $foo, $currentHTML);
```

Edit:

in your case:

```
   <?php 
    if ((isset($_POST["music1"])) && (isset($_POST["music2"])))  
    { 

    $foo = '
    <style>
        #myForm {
          display: none;
        }
    </style>
</header>';
$currentHTML = ob_get_contents();
$finalHTML = str_replace('</header>', $foo, $currentHTML);

file_put_contents($options[$_POST['music1']].'+'.'and'.'+'.$options[$_POST['music2']].'.html', $finalHTML);


    }
    // end buffering and displaying page
    ob_end_flush();

    ?>
```

Comment: because I need the form in the php file.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx That doesn't explain why you can't use css.

Comment: @Daedalus, it would be great if i could as it will make my job alot easier BUT how can i use NEW CSS in the newly generated HTML file?

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx The same way everyone else does.  Add a line or two to include a css file, or add inline styles, or add a style block in the document's head.

Comment: @Daedalus, I think you are missing the point mate! the HTML file is generated via PHP. the PHP file has already some CSS styling on it and when this New html file is generated, all the css styling in the php is also generated in it. I cannot add display:none; in my PHP file as I need the form to be on it. I just don't want it in the newly generated html file.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx You didn't explain that prior, and the way you spoke, you made it sound as if css was a possible solution.  Anyway, the post linked above has plenty examples of how to load the html into a string for parsing, and how to parse it and modify it.  Please read it in detail.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx I edited my answer, please see if it can be useful to your situation.

Comment: @Webinan The header tag is not what the document head is composed of.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx you mean you have an HTML without header tag? style tags don't have to be inside header tag. can you include your html sample?

Comment: @Webinan, It was Daedalus who commented on the header tags. my HTML has header tags.

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx sorry, tierd eyes... , so I think it's a quick fix if you don't want to use php DOM. And it should be fairly faster to run.

Comment: Nope, this didn't work! i have tried your hack and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @Webinan, I have edited my question now. am I missing something?

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx Oh no, check my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either!